# Generating C# code for a given .proto file produces an error while opening a file

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm working on Cpp-written dll, which will be used in my C# project. I use `google::protobuf::compiler::csharp::Generator` to generate .cs file.

First, I create `google::protobuf::compiler::Importer`. To do so, I need to get an instance of `DiskSourceTree` and implement `MultiFileErrorCollector`:

```
class ErrorCollector : public MultiFileErrorCollector
{
public:
    void AddError(const std::string& filename, int line, int column, const std::string& message) override
    {
        std::fstream stream;
        stream.open(filename);
        stream << message;
        stream.close();
    }
    void AddWarning(const std::string& filename, int line, int column, const std::string& message) override
    {
        std::fstream stream;
        stream.open(filename);
        stream << message;
        stream.close();
    }
};
```

After that, I implement `GeneratorContext` to pass it to `Generator::Generate()`:

```
class Context : public GeneratorContext
{
public:
    google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream* Open(const std::string& filename)
    {
        stream_ptr = std::make_unique<std::fstream>();
        stream_ptr->open(filename);
        proto_stream = std::make_unique<google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream>(stream_ptr.get());
        return proto_stream.get();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::fstream> stream_ptr;
    std::unique_ptr<google::protobuf::io::OstreamOutputStream> proto_stream;
};
```

The error occurs at the stage of importing `.proto`-file. The debugger says, `const google::protobuf::FileDescriptor* desc = importer->Import(FILENAME);` results to `null`.

It's probably something with the file path or even with my understanding of how it all works. I would appreciate any help.

Here's my `main` function:

```
int main()
{
        // building an Importer
        DiskSourceTree* tree = new DiskSourceTree;
        ErrorCollector* collector = new ErrorCollector;

        Importer* importer = new Importer(tree, collector);
    
        const std::string FILENAME = "C:/my/path/my_file.proto";
        const google::protobuf::FileDescriptor* desc = importer->Import(FILENAME); // the error is here
    
        // generating the code
        Generator generator;
        Context* context = new Context();
        std::string* error_str = new std::string;
        error_str->reserve(256);
    
        if (generator.Generate(desc, "", context, error_str)) // this line produces an exception since the descriptor is invalid
        {
            std::cout << "success!";
        }
    
        delete tree;
        delete collector;
        delete importer;
        delete context;
        delete error_str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, those were some extra code for a certain customization.

If all you do is generating a proto-class (in any supported language), you simply have to register the generator in `google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface`:

```
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h>
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_generator.h>

using namespace google::protobuf::compiler;    

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CommandLineInterface cli;    
    csharp::Generator generator;

    cli.RegisterGenerator("--cs_out", &generator, "Generate C# source.");
    return cli.Run(argc, argv);
 }
```

[Command line arguments and some other details](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.command_line_interface#CommandLineInterface)